# Not able to print hex bytes in C

Tags: c, serial-port, hex

I know this question has already been asked many times. I am facing a problem where I am getting few `hex bytes` via `serial communication` in `ubuntu`. I have written a C code which reads all the data and display it. It is working fine as I have tested it with many strings. I also have another system running windows and a software named `Docklight`. This software is giving me hex bytes and I need to receive it in my application.
Hex bytes are like below:

`FF AA 2E 0F CC 0D`

I have connected both the systems via null modem cable. Now to print hex bytes, we need to include `%02X` in printf  statement. Doing this, it gave me a warning of `format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned char *’`. I searched about this and replaced  it with `%p`. Here is the code:

```
unsigned char buf[255];

res = read(fd,buf,255);
buf[res]='\0';

printf("data: %p\n",buf);
```

The output of the printf statement is `data: 0x603380`. I opened the buf variable to see the exact values which are below:

```
Name : buf
Details:"ÿª.\017Ì\n", '\0' <repeats 248 times>
Default:0x603380 <buf>
Decimal:6304640
Hex:0x603380
Binary:11000000011001110000000
Octal:030031600
```

Now I really don't know why it shows random characters like `ÿª.\017Ì\n` The output of the printf is may be because it has combined all the bytes into one and displayed its hex equivalent.

I actually need to save each byte like `FF` and `AA` in an array. But just for the time being, I thought of first displaying it. What could be the issue. Why it is not displaying hex bytes. Can anyone give me suggestions on this. I also need to know that when we transmit hex bytes via serial, how does the receiving end should receive it. It should be saved as `int` or `strings`. Thanks.!

Comment: The output of your `printf` is because you're printing the base address of the first element of `buf` as a system-dependent formatted *pointer*. [See what `%p` does as a format specifier for `printf`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). In short, it doesn't do what you think it does. You need a *loop*. And fyi, your `buf` is only indexible from 0..254. If that `read` call fully populates with 255 octets, your unnecessary terminator placement on the subsequent line will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok. You mean I need a loop and convert each byte individually and save them in buffer.?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i< res; i++) printf["%02X", buf[i]); printf("\n");` BTW your buffer already contains that valkues, you don't need to convert them. What you are doing with printf is siply print them with ASCII format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a basic C problem, you are giving printf() a pointer and expecting it to show your hex dump, as if it was a string. That's not the way it works.

You should do something like this:

```
unsigned char buf[255];

res = read(fd,buf,255);
// AN HEX BUFFER IS NOT A STRING DO NOT TERMINATE IT
// buf[res]='\0';

printf("data: ");
for (int i = 0; i < res; ++i)
  printf("%02x ", (int)buf[i]);

printf("\n");
```

The option **%p** of printf it's used to dump the pointer ADDRESS, not the contents a pointer point to.

Comment: Thankyou I didnt know that we do not need to terminate string if it contains hex bytes. Also I was trying to save the converted hex bytes into an array by using sprintf like: `unsigned char hexarray[255]; for (int i = 0; i < res; ++i){sprintf(hexarray[i],"%02X",buf[i]);}` but it says argument 1 of sprintf makes pointer from integer without cast but buf is already char. How can I save the converted hex values in an another array

Comment: One more thing, printf output is `FF AA 2E 0F CC 0A`. It should be `FF AA 2E 0F CC 0D`. 0D  in the last byte is getting converted.

Comment: I think the problem is the line feed type, it's possible that a \r (0x0d) got translated to \n (0x0a) in the serial communication, both before transmission than after. If the sender is windows that's sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("data: %p\n",buf);
```

This is printing address of variable buf, as you have used %p
To display buf in hex, you need to print it in loop character by character

```
printf("data: %.2X\n",buf[i]);// i from 0 to res
```

"I actually need to save each byte like FF and AA in an array."
Its already in your array ie buf, you need to print it correctly, if you want to display in hex

Comment: I do not want to display. I need to just save the hex bytes in correct format in an array. So that later I can use the array element.