# CS50 - Recovery - Manipulating Card.raw PSET3

Tags: c, cs50, recover

So I'm a newbie struggling (drowning really) with C, trying to work my way through CS50. I'm working on the 'Recover' exercise, trying to recover jpegs from the card.raw file. Through Googling, I have learnt that by typing xxd -l 2400 card.raw (char is 'L') in terminal, I can display bytes 0-2384 inclusive in terminal, which are in the following format:

0000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................

0000950: 0fe0 c11b e555 8f20 33cc fbfe 559e 8eee  .....U. 3...U...

Q1: I want to display the first 32 bytes (all 0's) using printf (so I can verify what is being read). My program compiles, yet displays nothing. (Of course, once I have this working, I'll change it to display more bytes, as I know where the first jpeg starts from looking at the data in terminal).

Simple responses are appreciated (if I was more experienced, I wouldn't be posting such basic questions). Thanks,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    // hardcode opening of card.raw in read binary mode
    FILE *infile = fopen("card.raw", "rb");

    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open infile"); 
        return 2;
    } 

    // declare a variable to hold data to be read from infile file, note that a size for it must be specified
    char text[32];

    /* go to the beginning of the card.raw file to start reading */
    fseek(infile, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // text is the variable that will hold what is read, declared above
    // how many to read, how many to read at a time, where to read from
    fread(text, 32, 1, infile);
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

Comment: Basic questions are welcomed, but please post only one question per.

Comment: In a hex dump, the number on the left is the offset into the data and the data is represented by the hex data in the middle and the ascii representation of those hex values on the right. Hexdump a text file and you'll see how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to print hex bytes in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842053/not-able-to-print-hex-bytes-in-c)

Comment: You might also look here for questions and answers focused on CS50. https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks DinoCoderSAurus, with your (and some other help), I was able to figure out the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    // hardcode opening of a file with fopen, in read binary mode
    FILE *infile = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
    // error check, did file open?
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open infile"); 
        return 2;
    }

    // because card.raw contains binary/hex data, must use unsigned char to hold data, 32 bytes chosen at random
    unsigned char dataval[32];

    //    dataval is the variable that will hold what is read, declared above
    //          how many to read, how many to read at a time, where to read from
    fread(dataval, 1, 32, infile);

    //Print bytes (from dataval) one at a time
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X ", (int)dataval[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of significant problems. First this declaration `char text[32];`. Recall that `char` has a very specific meaning, it is evaluated as integers from 0 to 255; it is "signed". That is perfect for reading ascii text. Recall/review bmp.h from `resize` to see how data should be declared to read data that is *not* ascii text, like image data.

-- edit --   Binary data needs to be an "unsigned" data type. In bmp.h, the author used `uint8_t` here `typedef uint8_t  BYTE;` (which requires `#include stdint.h>`). You could use
 `unsigned char text[32]`

Secondly this `printf("%s\n", text);`. `text` is declared an array of chars. But remember the thing that makes a string a string? It is the terminating null byte, technically `0`. So when you ask printf to print `text` as a string it will print everything up to the first null byte (`0`).  Which, as you can see from your hex dump, is the first byte in the file.

--edit-- Since you cannot use a string format in printf, you can print the ouptut one character at a time, much like mario or caesar. However, since it is unsigned, the format string would be `%u` instead of `%c`. You can see it in hex with the format string `%04x` (`x` is the specifier for hex).

Comment: Thanks, but your hints are still well above my head. I know that the first 32 bytes are  0's, and just don't know how to display them in either C or python from the Card.raw file. I reviewed the bmp.h file, but don't fully appreciate the difference with Byte, Dword, Long, Word that I think you're pointing me to. (I don't really care about the first 32 bytes, I just want to print something on screen so I can see I'm accessing the right data).

Comment: I have added more specific info in the answer. I hope it gets you on the right path.