# jpg's are not proper, mix of multiple images. Can anyone tell me whats wrong?“RECOVER”

Tags: c, cs50, recover

I am working on CS50's PSET3 recover. I have a "card.raw" file in which jpg's are arranged one after another after the first one.

The objectives of the exercise is "find first jpg by scanning 512 bytes each time and checking if it is the starting of a jpg then adding next bytes to the file until next jpg start is found, then opening another file and repeating until the END OF FILE".

The images are not getting produced properly and I'm not sure where my problem lies in the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check if program argument count is correct
    if ( argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return(1);
    }

    char *infile = argv[1];    //Remember file name

    //open file for reading
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile,"r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return(2);
    }

    typedef uint8_t BYTE;      //new name BYTE

    BYTE buffer[512];          // temporary  storage

    int counter = 0;           // image counter

    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr) == 1)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            char filename[8];

            start:
            sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg", counter);
            FILE *outptr = fopen(filename,"w");
            fwrite(buffer, 512, 1,outptr);

            //check next byte
             while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, inptr) == 1)
             {
                  if (buffer[0] != 0xff && buffer[1] != 0xd8 && buffer[2] != 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) != 0xe0)
                  {
                      fwrite(buffer, 512, 1,outptr);
                      printf("%i",counter);
                  }

                  //if next file starts
                  if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                  {
                      counter++;
                      printf("%i",counter);
                      fclose(outptr);
                      goto start;
                  }
             }
             if (counter > 1)
             {
                 fclose(outptr);
             }
        }
    }
    fclose(inptr);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be posted in https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pset3 instead of here?

Comment: ya i did post it there too,i thought it would be better to post it on both(different) websites.Should i remove it?

Comment: added additional information, and completed the program .

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726027/cs50-recovery-manipulating-card-raw-pset3 which appears to be on the same topic and exercise.

Comment: i was hesitating from adding full code as last time i did that, website mentioned that i just copy pasted all code, so i wasn't allowed to post. i had to chop down the code.

Comment: and Thanks , I'll look in that link if i could find similar problems and understand.

Comment: The code to detect the change in file is quite clumsy. You checked it once and then you check it again, what is already known. Acutally, about 3 times. I would revise the flow control and get rid of the ugly `goto`.

Comment: I check the code 2 times and use it both time  immediately both times and then the process repeats itself, i'm a newbie couldn't find a better way.^_^

Comment: In such codes, the usual method seen is to detect the jpeg signature *once* and if found, close the current file, generate the next file name, open a new file and continue, closing it when there is no more data to be read. No `goto` is needed, and no nested loop. A single loop is all that is required: read each block; jpeg signature? close file, open new file; write block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could have written better code, but if its just about logic then

```
if (buffer[0] != 0xff && buffer[1] != 0xd8 && buffer[2] != 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) != 0xe0)
                  {
                      fwrite(buffer, 512, 1,outptr);
                      printf("%i",counter);
                  }
```

This is wrong, it should be

```
if (!(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0))
                  {
                      fwrite(buffer, 512, 1,outptr);
                      printf("%i",counter);
                  }
```

As the previous also neglects any part of jpg that have one or more of first 4 bytes equal to start of IMG but not all.
Thank you everyone for helping.